# Why is there no implementation of `IntoIterator` for smart pointers?

Tags: rust

It seems like it should be possible to write:

```rust
impl<T> IntoIterator for &T
where
    T:  Deref,
    &(T::Target): IntoIterator,
{
  type Item = (&(T::Target))::Item;
  type IntoIter = (&(T::Target))::IntoIter;

  fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
    self.deref().into_iter()
  }
}
```

The orphan rule prevents implementing this outside of the standard library.

What is the technical or ergonomics reason this isn't in the standard library? Or, if `Deref` is too wide, a reason why there isn't an `IntoIterator` for `&Arc<T>` or `&Box<T>`?

Comment: This seems like an odd question: many datatypes are not iterable, why would you need a blanket implementation? Maybe there's something I'm missing here...

Comment: What you be the point of this? Wherever you could pass `IntoIterator` you can explicitly do the dereferation yourself.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze well, skip the manual deref, precisely; `for x in p` instead of `for x in &*p`.

Comment: @JaredSmith the `&(T::Target): IntoIterator` constraint?

Comment: Providing this via generic+`Deref` sounds too over-reaching to me, but pass-through implementations on `Box` and `Arc` does sound reasonable to me (many other traits are implemented on smart pointers like this). Perhaps consider filing an issue on the Rust repository to propose it? I found [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/59878) though it is a slightly different goal since yours is for references.

Comment: on second look, that issue I linked looks almost entirely unrelated, oops

Comment: @kmdreko The impl for `Box` cannot be written because it conflicts with `impl<T: Iterator> Iterator for Box<T>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman OP seems to be asking about `IntoIterator` for `&Box<T>`, not `Box<T>`. Sorry if my wording was imprecise.

Comment: @kmdreko I see no reason to provide an implementation just for `&T`. Makes more sense to omit it altogether.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman makes as much sense as any other trait on `Box` that treats it transparently IMO: see `Read`, `Write`, `Hash`, `Future`, etc. Not sure what you mean by "just for `&T`", I thought we were talking specifically about `Box`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost it [clashes with the existing `impl<I> IntoIterator for I where I: Iterator`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c74f38db326ffb27121f2ea5929dc29a) it's also totally unnecessary, `into_iter` is available through deref:

```rust
let b = Box::new([1, 2]);
for e in b.into_iter() {
    dbg!(e);
}
```

works.

The clash occurs because there is no way to guarantee that a type won't implement both `Deref` and `Iterator`.

Comment: Right, `b.into_iter()` is available through deref, but `&*b` works too; I'd just really like to write just `b`.

Comment: Took me a moment to realize why the clash would occur. Nice.

Comment: In general you can only have one blanket implementation per trait.